# How to display static website inside GitHub Readme markdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, markdown

Given: a static website hosted via an s3 public bucket
And An existing markdown file which is part of a public GitHub repo

How can I modify the markdown to render the static website when someone is viewing the rendered markdown?

Comment: Have you tried using `<iframe>`?

Comment: I don't think you can. GitHub strips a bunch of stuff out as part of its rendering pipeline for Markdown, which I'm pretty sure includes `<iframe>`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.  The purpose of GitHub's README rendering is to render the specific contents of the file in the repository for easy reading by the user.  It's not to render unrelated sites.

Moreover, allowing this would allow tracking of users and potentially security problems, which GitHub doesn't want.  Even if you could somehow sneak an iframe past the filters in the rendering pipeline, the `Content-Security-Policy` header provided disallows any frames, and the user's browser would notify GitHub that the policy was violated.

You can include a link to the site if you wish, which will work just fine.